# The above error occurred in the <ScrollView> component

Tags: javascript, react-native, jestjs, scrollview

console.error
The above error occurred in the  component:

```
      at ScrollViewMock (/Users/arqum/Desktop/support/faveo-support-app/node_modules/react-native/jest/mockScrollView.js:21:52)
      at _class (/Users/arqum/Desktop/support/faveo-support-app/node_modules/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view/lib/KeyboardAwareHOC.js:199:47)
      at View
      at Component (/Users/arqum/Desktop/support/faveo-support-app/node_modules/react-native/jest/mockComponent.js:28:18)
      at ChangePasswordScreen (/Users/arqum/Desktop/support/faveo-support-app/src/components/functionality/LoginUser/ChangePassword/ChangePassword.js:17:24)
  
  Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
  Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.

  at logCapturedError (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:10989:23)
  at update.callback (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:11022:5)
  at callCallback (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:3662:12)
  at commitUpdateQueue (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:3683:9)
  at commitLifeCycles (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:11855:11)
  at commitLayoutEffects (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:14443:7)
  at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackProd (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:11308:10)
  at invokeGuardedCallback (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:11499:31)
```

● Language Screen Components and Unit Testing › Get Update Language Component

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'major')

  at Object.extractNativeRef (node_modules/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view/lib/KeyboardAwareHOC.js:135:93)
  at _this._handleRef (node_modules/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view/lib/KeyboardAwareHOC.js:508:52)
  at commitAttachRef (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:11992:7)
  at commitLayoutEffects (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:14448:9)
  at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackProd (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:11308:10)
  at invokeGuardedCallback (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:11499:31)
  at commitRootImpl (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:14172:9)
  at unstable_runWithPriority (node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js:468:12)
  at runWithPriority (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:2486:10)
  at commitRoot (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:14011:3)
```

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 passed, 2 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.379 s, estimated 2 s
Ran all test suites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading through this [github issue](https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view/issues/493), I was able to resolve the error with the following code.

Taken from this [comment](https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view/issues/493#issuecomment-1023551697) in the thread.

```js
jest.mock('react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view', () => {
  const KeyboardAwareScrollView = require('react-native').ScrollView;
  return { KeyboardAwareScrollView };
});
```

This mocks the `KeyboardAwareScrollView` using the React Native `ScrollView`.